# Save query in table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL query that look like this

```
select distinct v.col1, v.col2, v.col3
from table v
where v.col1 is not null
```

I would like to save the result set returned from this query into a completely new table called `test`.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If i understand you, you can use `SELECT .... INTO .... FROM...`. But if you want up to date values try with views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard method to create a new *table* uses `create table as`:

```
create table new_table as
    select distinct v.col1, v.col2, v.col3
    from table v
    where v.col1 is not null;
```

Not all databases support this construct; for instance, SQL Server uses `into`:

```
select distinct v.col1, v.col2, v.col3
into new_table
from table v
where v.col1 is not null;
```

You may find that a view is sufficient, but a view is different from a table -- it is executed each time it is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a view like that :

```sql
CREATE VIEW [View_name] AS
select distinct v.col1, v.col2, v.col3
from table v
where v.col1 is not null
```

more info about view : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp